# R vector into String of Strings

Tags: sql, r, paste

I'm new to both R and mySQL and would like to run the following mysql command in R

```
query = "select x, y from table where z in ('a', 'b');"
sqlQuery(connection, query)
```

Suppose I have a very long vector of variable length. Is it possible to do

```
vector = c('a','b', .....)
query = "select x, y from table where z in **vector**;"
```

I tried

```
query = paste("select x, y from table where z in (", paste(vector, collapse =', '), ");")
```

but I lose quotes in the brackets and I get

```
query = "select x, y from table where z in (a, b);"
```

which does not run in sqlQuery.  Is there a way to use the paste command so that I get a string of strings?  Or is there a better way to do what I would like to accomplish?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `shQuote`

```
query <- paste("select x, y from table where z in (", paste(shQuote(vector, type = "sh"), 
         collapse = ', '), ");")
query
[1] "select x, y from table where z in ( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );"
```

Comment: That is an even nicer solution, +1!

Comment: This is OS-dependent. You'll get something different by default under Windows, for example.

Comment: @HongOoi It's not OS dependent (at least in my linux box) but propose different quoting type for different shell (`type` parameter). I have access to all parameter in my linux Box (I can use type = "cmd"). I don't have a windows machine to check but it's strange

Comment: @HongOoi Edited to specify the type. Now, it's OS agnostic.

Comment: Have a look at the code for `shQuote`. You'll see a specific check for Windows to set the `type` argument if it's missing. Of course you can _force_ a particular quoting style with `type`, but that should be made clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can surround the `'` by `"` to make them really part of the string:

```
vector = c("'a'","'b'", .....)
```

An example:

```
> vec = c("'a'", "'b'", "'c'")
> paste(vec, collapse = ', ')
[1] "'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your vector in quotes before pasting it into your query.

```
vector <- paste0("'", vector, "'", collapse=", ")

query <- paste("select ....", vector, <etc>)
```

`shQuote` does this for you, but this is an abuse of its purpose. It's meant for quoting strings for the *OS shell*, and there's no guarantee that its default choice will be what your database expects. For example, on Windows it wraps everything in double quotes, which is what `cmd.exe` expects, but which might break the query string.